# Ask login to append chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some classical JQuery / JavaScript code where I append a bunch of elements using method chaining.

```
jQuery('<div>').addClass('HEADER').append(
                    jQuery('<span>').addClass('TARGET ').html('&nbsp;').css('width', '25px')
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<span>').addClass('NAME HEADER').text(localization.opportunity).css('width', defaultNameSize-paddingTotal)
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<span>').addClass('HEIGHT HEADER').text(localization.amount)
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<span>').addClass('ANSWER HEADER').css('display', 'none').text(localization.solution)
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<span>').addClass('VALUETYPE HEADER').text(localization.type)
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<span>').addClass('VALUETOLEFT HEADER').css('display', 'none').text(abbreviate(CAT_VALUETOUS))
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<span>').addClass('VALUETORIGHT HEADER').css('display', 'none').text(abbreviate(CAT_VALUETOTHEM))
                )
```

I want to only append an element in the middle only if such and such a condition is true.  I could split this up into three different methods chains and add logic to the middle to see if such and such an element should be appended.

But, I was wondering was there a more elegant solution?

Thanks

Comment: What are the conditions that trigger whether to insert the element and what sort of element is inserted? There are all sorts of ways that this could be interpreted. Please post all relevant code.

Comment: BTW, you might want to start thinking about using client-side templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a conditional operator to optionally pass `null` to `.append()` if your condition is not satisfied. jQuery won't mind.

```
// snip
.append(...)
.append(someBoolean ? jQuery(...) : null)
.append(...)
// snip
```

Note [there is a more compact syntax for creating elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) than what you're using:

```
jQuery('<span>', { 'class': 'foo', text: 'bar', css: 'baz' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of objects representing the elements you wish to append. For example

```
var elements = [{ element: '<span>',
                  class: 'TARGET',
                  html: 'stuff',
                  text: 'node text'
               }];

$(elements).each(function(i, element) {
    // your logic here
    $('<div>')
       .append(element.element)
       .addClass(element.class)
       .html(element.html)
       .text(element.text);
});
```